# C++ - Method overloading over different classes

Tags: c++, smtp, overloading

So there's is exercise for an smtp server..

> Define a class for each of the commands [HELO,MAIL FROM, RCPT TO,
>   DATA] . These classes should be immutable and must therefore take all
>   the parameters required to build the command in the constructor.
>   Additionally, create an SMTPServer class that has a send() function
>   that returns void and is overloaded four times, one for each command.

I have a good idea of what function overloading is, however I don't quite understand some parts:

1) how does function overloading actually work over many classes? must I involve inheritance?

2) Why bother creating a send() function in the SMTPServer? I assume that all that is needed is to create an instance of each command in the main and send what is required.

Sidenote:
Commands are as follows:

- HELO followed by an identication string.
- MAIL FROM followed by the recipient's email address.
- RCPT TO followed by the sender's email address.
- DATA followed by the subject and the email contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, you do not involve inheritance - they are asking you to overload the `send` member function of the `SMTPServer` class so that each can take a different command class as a parameter:

```
void SMTPServer::send(HELO command);
void SMTPServer::send(MAIL_FROM command);
void SMTPServer::send(RCPT_TO command);
void SMTPServer::send(DATA command);
```

2) Because that is how OOP works - you encapsulate each responsibility of your program into a class ([Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). In this particular case, SMTPServer is responsible for communicating commands. The job of `main` is simply to set up the various objects and call their functions to do the actual work of your program.